# Why does np.add.at() return the wrong answer for large arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large data set, `statistic`, with `statistic.shape = (1E10,)` that I want to effectively bin (sum) into an array of zeros, `out = np.zeros(1E10)`. Each entry in `statistic` has a corresponding index, `idx`, which tells me in which `out` bin it belongs. The indices are not unique so I cannot use `out += statistic[idx]` since this will only count the first time a particular index is encountered. Therefore I'm using `np.add.at(out, idx, statistic)`. My problem is that for very large arrays, np.add.at() returns the wrong answer.

Below is an example script that shows this behaviour. The function `check_add()` should return 1.

```py
import numpy as np

def check_add(N):
    N = int(N)
    out = np.zeros(N)
    np.add.at(out, np.arange(N), np.ones(N))
    return np.sum(out)/N

n_arr = [1E3, 1E5, 1E8, 1E10]
for n in n_arr:
    print('N = {} (log(N) = {}); output ratio is {}'.format(n, np.log10(n), check_add(n)))
```

This example returns for me:

```
N = 1000.0 (log(N) = 3.0); output ratio is 1.0
N = 100000.0 (log(N) = 5.0); output ratio is 1.0
N = 100000000.0 (log(N) = 8.0); output ratio is 1.0
N = 10000000000.0 (log(N) = 10.0); output ratio is 0.1410065408
```

Can someone explain to me why the function fails for `N=1E10`?

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `out` after the `add.at` operation?

Comment: And what NumPy version are you on?

Comment: Also, what OS? Some NumPy code paths are OS-dependent.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 and using NumPy 1.16.0. I have looked at `out` and it seems that it fills the array with 1 as expected until `out[1410065408]`. After that it is all 0.

Comment: Weird. Too bad this takes a crazy amount of memory to test.

Comment: What do you get if you `print(numpy.intp)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old bug, [NumPy issue 13286](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13286). `ufunc.at` was using a too-small variable for the loop counter. It got [fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/6dac2d6a4a061a39cc41f93641c0c29085cd10a6) a while ago, so update your NumPy. (The fix is present in 1.16.3 and up.)

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the help. @DanielF, sadly I can't give you 90% of the credit. If I could, I would.

Answer (score 1):

You're overflowing `int32`:

```
1E10 % (np.iinfo(np.int32).max - np.iinfo(np.int32).min + 1)  # + 1 for 0
Out[]: 1410065408
```

There's your weird number (googling that number actually got me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673666/why-100000001000-giving-1410065408-in-java) which is how I figured this out.)

Now, what's happening in your function is a bit more weird.  By the documentation of `ufunc.at` you should just be accumulate-adding the `1` values in the indices that are lower than `np.iinfo(np.int32).max` and the negative indices above `np.iinfo(np.int32).min` - but it seems to be 1) working backwards and 2) stopping when it gets to the *last* overflow.  Without digging into the `c` code I couldn't tell you why, but it's probably a good thing it does - your function would fail silently and with the "correct" mean if it had done things this way, while corrupting your results (having `2` or `3` in those indices and `0` in the middle).

Comment: It *should* just work - int32 shouldn't be involved at all. Something in the C code may be using a too-small data type somewhere.

Comment: [Found it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/6dac2d6a4a061a39cc41f93641c0c29085cd10a6) - there was an `int` that should have been a `numpy_intp` in the `ufunc.at` source code.

Comment: Figured as much, but I am not at all qualified to dig through `c` code.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to integer precision indeed. If you play around with the numpy data-type (e.g. you constrain it to an (unsigned) value between 0-255) by setting `uint8`, you will see that they ratios start declining already for the second array. I do not have enough memory to test it, but setting all dtypes to `uint64` as below should help:

```
def check_add(N):
    N = int(N)
    out = np.zeros(N,dtype='uint64')
    np.add.at(out, np.arange(N,dtype='uint64'), 1)
    return np.sum(out)/N
```

To understand the behavior, I recommend setting `dtype='uint8'` and checking the behavior for smaller N. So what happens is that the `np.arange` function creates ascending integers for the vector elements until it reaches the integer limit. It then starts again at 0 and counts up again, so at the beginning (smaller Ns) you get correct sum (although your `out` vector contains a lot of elements >1 in the positions 0:limit and a lot of elements = 0 beyond the limit). If however you choose N large enough, the elements in your `out` vector start exceeding the integer limit and start again from 0. As soon as that happens your sum is vastly off. To double-check, realize that the uint8 limit is 255(256 integers) and 256^2=65536. Set N = 65536 with `dtype='uint8'` and `check_add(65536)` will return 0.

import numpy as np

```
def check_add(N):
    N = int(N)
    out = np.zeros(N,dtype='uint8')
    np.add.at(out, np.arange(N,dtype='uint8'), 1)
    return np.sum(out)/N

n_arr = [1E1, 1E3, 1E5,65536, 1E7]
for n in n_arr:
    print('N = {} (log(N) = {}); output ratio is {}'.format(n, np.log10(n), check_add(n)))
```

Also note, that you don't need the `np.ones` vector but can simply replace it by 1, if all you care about is uniformly incrementing everything by 1.

Comment: But the original `out` and `ones` dtypes were already float64, which isn't subject to integer overflow and has enough precision to handle all operations involved.

Comment: The original arange dtype would have been int64, which is also plenty.

Comment: Afaik, the default datatype for np.arange is int32, which is not enough to handle 1E10. I don't believe this is a bug, but mathematical behavior.

Comment: The default dtype for numpy.arange depends on the arguments and the OS, but regardless of OS, `numpy.arange(int(1e10))` will use int64 dtype.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing as I couldn't run it, but could it be a problem that you are exceeding max integer value in python for the last option? Ie exceeds 2147483647.
Use longinteger type instead as per below.

Referring to: [enter link description here][1]https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/integers.html

Hope this helps. Please let me know if it does work.

Comment: That is severely out of date, NumPy math works differently from regular Python ints anyway, and `out` has float64 dtype, not integer dtype. It's likely that some overflow effect is involved somewhere, but Python 2 `long` isn't the solution.

Comment: Good to know. Would be good to know what the issue is. Never came across this before.